# Understanding MultiThreading : Random Output in Unsynchronous Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

Online link of the code:
https://onlinegdb.com/rkdjD1eIr

The code:

```
class SomeThread extends Thread{

    static volatile int count;
     public void run(){     
        System.out.println("count value unsync"+count);
        synchronized(SomeThread.class){
            count = count + 1;
            System.out.println("Thread number = "+ (count));
        }

    }

}

class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        for(int i =0;i<20;i++){
            SomeThread t = new SomeThread();
            t.start();
            //t.join();
            for(int j=0;j<1000000;j++);
            //t.sleep(100);
        }

    }
}
```

When I run the given program, I get this output :

```
count value unsync0
count value unsync1
count value unsync1
Thread number = 1
Thread number = 2
Thread number = 3
count value unsync3
Thread number = 4
count value unsync4
Thread number = 5
count value unsync5
Thread number = 6
count value unsync6
Thread number = 7
count value unsync7
Thread number = 8
count value unsync8
Thread number = 9
count value unsync0   
// How is the count value displayed as 0 when count was just set to 9 
count value unsync0
Thread number = 10
count value unsync0
count value unsync10
count value unsync10
count value unsync10
count value unsync10
count value unsync10
Thread number = 11
count value unsync0
count value unsync0
Thread number = 12
Thread number = 13
Thread number = 14
count value unsync0
Thread number = 15
Thread number = 16
Thread number = 17
Thread number = 18
Thread number = 19
Thread number = 20
```

How is the The count value decreased in the unsyncrhonized part ?
My understanding is that, the count value is displayed by the thread it whenever it gets that chance to run it. 
So if the thread 1 comes and increases the value of count variable, the value of count should be 1 for all the threads since the I have described the count variable as static. So the count variable should be shared by every thread.

So at no point should the value of count be less than the value it was set at in the synchronized block. 
Meaning, if the count value is set to 1, it should always display count value greater than 1 or equal to one.

Expected output is : The value of count should never be less than the previously displayed value of count;

Answer (score 0):

One of the threads might have completed the sentence (added the int to the String) but then, for some reason, had to wait a while. In the meantime, the other threads are outputting all sorts of values. By the time the first, slow, thread gets it's turn to output the sentence, it is already outdated.